# Creating a Basic JS Library for Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, shared-libraries

I've been working to build some front-end components with CSS and some JS code.  I've built the JS library using TypeScript and some vanilla JS.  The structure of my code is:

- /src/alert.ts
- /src/modal.ts
- /src/dropdown.ts
- etc...

Each script file is laid out roughly like this:

```
export class Modal {
  constructor(element: Element|string, options: ModalOptions) {
    doSometing();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to compile my library and bring it into my Angular application like:

```
import { Modal } from 'mylibrary';

let modalInst = new Modal(Element, {
  someProperty: true
});
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm missing in order to get Angular to see my classes as modules.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, all you need to know are well described in the officiel [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)

Comment: Then for local use, you need to install your lib in your main project : https://dev.to/patelvimal/how-to-use-angular-library-locally-with-hot-module-reload-2m35

Comment: Are you packaging this up as a library that you're deploying to an artifact registry like npmjs?

Comment: @joffery Just to make sure I'm not getting my terminology confused.  I am not trying to build angular specific components, but rather css and js based components similar to Bootstrap.  So do I still need to create an Angular library in order to achieve this?

Comment: @mfaith Yes, to some degree I am trying to package it in that way, but only plan to use it privately and not publish it publicly.

Comment: @NathanielEldridge no, you wouldn't necessarily need to build it as an Angular library if you're not using Angular specific capabilities.  You *would* need to have built and packaged in the right way though.  As in, have proper typescript .d.ts files and have the ability to import as esm modules. Are you using Rollup to bundle the library?  Also, what does your tsconfig look like?